# How could I install a previous version of ROS?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had ros **1.1.3-0trusty-20140805-0935-+0000** in my machine earlier. I had a ros package I build from source worked fine with this version. However, after I upgraded my ros to  **1.1.4-0trusty-20160208-135350-0800**, above package even after I build from source again won't work anymore.

So how could I downgrade my ros version to  **1.1.3-0trusty-20140805-0935-+0000**
(using apt-get)

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228548/how-could-i-install-a-previous-version-of-ros?/) by [japzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24275/japzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-03-09**:
In general a patch release should not break your code. Can you explain more about what no longer works and what specific package you're referring to the version of? There is no "ros" package. I suspect that there's a better way to get your system working than downgrading this patch version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Theo Answers is no, because only the News packets arge hosted. The only thing  you can Pool the Version form git of ros and build the whole ros  System form source.

Or you have a working backup.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [japzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24275/japzi/) on 2016-03-08**:
Thanks. I compiled the source ros-indigo-desktop. Now, I need to build robot perception packages. For example, how could I build a package vision_opencv (https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv) from source?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few years passed from the accepted answer and there's now a "snapshot" repository on `ros.org` where DEB files (for Debian, Ubuntu) timestamped binary packages are available. See the announcement [discourse.ros.org#7705](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-ros-snapshot-repositories/7705/13).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2020-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2